# what approach should I follow to check duplicate references id

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

I have some service which communicate with a central Core-service. Every time service pass Reference Id to Core-service and Core service check the duplicate data and store Reference Id along the service request. Now I checking the duplicate data from DB table .Which is too much time consuming. The Reference Id is generated in service. Reference Id cant be generated from one point in this case.
1.How to check duplicate data with less time lose ?
2.Do I need any NoSQL db for Reference Id check ?
or any thing else ?

Comment: Do you want to check duplicate records in a SQL table?

Comment: Yes ..I want to ..but the table has more than millions of data  and the table data size increase continuously.

Comment: DO you want to check the duplicate reference Ids?

Answer (score 0):

Following query will return the duplicate reference Ids in the table.

```
SELECT referenceId, COUNT(referenceId)
FROM table
GROUP BY referenceId
HAVING COUNT(referenceId) > 1
```